# What do I need to install to Xcode to develop Apple Tv apps?

Tags: jailbreak, cydia, apple-tv

I'm currently searching for a plugin that installs the required frameworks to program apps for a jailbroken Apple Tv but I can't find it. If anyone knows of anything please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Go here http://www.iosopendev.com

It installs stuff to Xcode making it easier to develop for jailbroken devices. You can start there for the Apple TV